# What does "ctx" mean?

Tags: c, abbreviation

I have seen it used twice already in different libraries as an abbreviation, but I can't wrap my head around what it should mean.

For example here:

```
static int reformat_string(void * ctx, const unsigned char * stringVal,  
                       size_t stringLen)  
{  
    yajl_gen g = (yajl_gen) ctx;  
    return yajl_gen_status_ok == yajl_gen_string(g, stringVal, stringLen);  
}
```

As far as I can tell, it is usually used for structs.

Comment: While refactoring some piece of Java code, I changed variable name `ctx` to `context` which raised some questions from a reviewer. "Is `ctx` not clear enough?" In Java, I prefer fully spelt out variable names unless there is a very good reason to contract/abreviate. Hope this gives you some food for thought.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

It typically stands for "context".  Usually this is some structure that gets passed around to functions in a library, used to maintain state (i.e., the [context](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/context) of the function call).

It's a preferable alternative to using global variables.

Answer (score 0):

By acronymsandslang.com It means "context".
But You can look for other [CTX meaning](http://acronymsandslang.com/definition/447898/CTX-meaning.html) there

Comment: I'm not sure I would consider that site a useful reference for this domain.